# Files in directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory

How to get all files in a given directory using C++ on windows?

Note:
I found methods that use `dirent.h` but I need a more standard way...

Thanks

Comment: Actually, the functions in dirent.h are the more standard (POSIX) way.

Comment: But the file is not included in VC++ 2008

Comment: @Neil: POSIX is not part of the standard library and it is not well supported by the most used C/C++ compiler (MSVC) of the most used operating system (Windows).

Comment: @Lorenzo POSIX is a standard - Windows isn't. But from your other posts here I don't see much point in arguing the point.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant whether POSIX is more standard than Windows or not. The original question is clearly related to Windows, and thus talking about `dirent.h` makes absolutely no sense and is not helpful.

Comment: @Phillip The questioner introduced dirent.h, not me. And I use it in my Windows code all the time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows/2315808#2315808

Answer (score 30):

Use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and related functions. Example:

```
HANDLE hFind;
WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

hFind = FindFirstFile("c:\\*.*", &data);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  do {
    printf("%s\n", data.cFileName);
  } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
  FindClose(hFind);
}
```

Comment: @Lorenzo: The one that casablanca used, called "ANSI" by the MSDN Library (the term "8-bit" is technically correct, but seems to be used by me exclusively). It is only included for compatibility with Windows 9x. The native API is UTF-16. To use it, define `UNICODE` everywhere and replace 8-bit functions like `printf` either by generic macros (`_tprintf`) or the UTF-16 function (`_wprintf`), and use "wide" string constants with the `L` prefix or the `TEXT` macro. See your own posting for a better example (still without `UNICODE` because that should be defined via a compiler switch).

Comment: @Philipp: now makes more sense, but if you say "8-bit API" it will hardly be interpreted as "non-UNICODE API". In my opinion it doesn't deserves a -1, as there's no real need to add complexity to a sample adding TEXT() macro and _txxx functions.

Comment: @Philipp: This is an example for listing files, not about text output, and `printf` serves the purpose well here. I could have even used `MessageBox` instead of `printf`, but well, that's not the point.

Comment: @casablanca: Yes, it's not about text output, but there are already so many examples that unnecessarily use the obsolete API that another one is not required. @Lorenzo: You don't have to add `TEXT` macros if you don't want, you can use wide strings (`L"…"`) instead. But you *must* do one of these on Windows, otherwise your program is broken.

Comment: @Philipp: You're confusing `UNICODE` (selects Win32 API, such as `FindFirstFileA/W`) and `_UNICODE` (selects MS CRT API, such as `printf`/`wprintf`)

Comment: @MSalters: Indeed I forgot to mention `_UNICODE`; both are required (and `NOMINMAX` and `STRICT` should also be defined). In this case I'd say that `UNICODE` is the more important switch because it selects `FindFirstFileW`.

Comment: @casablanca: You could add #include<Windows.h> in the begining. But nice answer anyway

Answer (score 10):

What about the boost library: filesystem.
[Boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html)

Comment: +1 for Boost. You might want to link to the filesystem docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: It depends on the definition of the word "standard." If you only accept ISO standards, then there is no standard way at all. `FindFirstFile` is the accepted OS interface for listing directory entries, and Boost.Filesystem is just a wrapper around this interface on Windows. Both are de-facto standards.

Comment: The standard on Windows is to stay as far away from the Win32 API as possible. If Boost offers a sane alternative, that's the reflex of a lot of C++ developers would be to jump at it.

Comment: @Philipp: but the user asked the standard way *in WIndows*.

Comment: @Lorenzo: As I said, it depends on what you mean with "standard." The API solution is just fine: it's easy to use, flexible and doesn't introduce additional dependencies. But it's not standardized in the sense that there is an ISO standard for it.

Comment: @jalf: Generally I favor Boost over the Windows API, but in this case the API returns more information and is fairly easy to use, so I wouldn't recommend against it unless OS independence is required.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the `FindFirstFile` function ([documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx)). This is the standard (and preferred) way *in Windows*, however it is not portable. The header `dirent.h` you have found contains the definition of the [standard POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h) functions.

For the full code look at this example: [Listing the Files in a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted standard for C++ is described in <strike>[N1975](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1975.html)</strike> ISO/IEC TS 18822:2015, latest draft is [N4100](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf). Your compiler might not have it yet, in which case [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) provides essentially the same.