# Get list of directories in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, directory

I have to believe that this question must have been already answered multiple times, but I cannot find it.   Using Visual Studio C (not C++ or C#), how do I get a list of directories inside another directory?   I've tried searching "get list of directories" and "get list of folders" and "find folders in a directory".

Can someone enlighten me as to 1) actually get a directory list and 2) what I am doing wrong in my choice of search terms that I am unable to find what I think should be a relatively frequent question.

Comment: I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx)  is about as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from *NTDLS* should solve your problem:
[Listing directory contents using C and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)

You have to change the function so the files would be skipped but that shouldn't be the problem. If you don't want to list all the folders of the subdirectorys: leave out the recursive call in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

EX: compile as Dirc.exe,
    usage: dirc -d [Directory]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main();
void get_args();
void help();

void get_args(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

            if (argv[i][0] == '-') {

                switch (argv[i][1]) {

        case 'd': for (i = 2; i < argc; i++){
              struct dirent *dp;
                      DIR *dfd = opendir(argv[i]);
                        if(dfd != NULL) {
                      while((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL)
                  printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);
                      closedir(dfd);
                        }
              }
                break;

        default:    
        fprintf(stderr,
                "\nERROR: Unknown switch %s\n", argv[i]);
                help();
        }

      } else {
                for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
                printf("%s ", argv[i]);}
            }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        get_args(argc, argv);
        if (argc==1){ help();}
}

void help()
{
    printf("\n Usage: dirc.exe [Arguments] [Dir]\n");
    printf(" Example: dirc -y words\n");
    printf("\n Arguments:");
        printf("\n -d |Directory|");
}
```

Comment: This will list all directory entries, not just directory entries that are directories themselves as OP asked. On *nix you could use stat(2) on each directory entry to determine its type (directory or something else). I'm sure there's something similar on Windows (maybe even stat(2) itself).

Comment: This doesn't work in VS2010 C (console app) because there is no equivalent dirent.h file in that environment.

Comment: @Giel what about including this file http://linux.die.net/include/sys/stat.h ?, found it on: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat ? is this the one?

Comment: @JoeDF: if <sys/stat.h> is available with your compiler that has a good chance of working. Probably does with MinGW which has a POSIX compatibility library, but with VSC I honestly wouldn't know (last time I used that was 2005ish).