# How to access directory files in C?

Tags: c, file-io, directory

I'm trying to add all the files in the current directory to my implemented archive. What function(s) could I use to access all these files? After doing some research online and in the man pages, all I have found is simple I/O like read, write, close, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this.

```
main() {
   DIR *d;
   struct dirent *e;

   e=malloc(sizeof(struct dirent));
   d=opendir("<your_directory_name>");

   while ((e = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
      printf("%d %s\n", e->d_type, e->d_name);
   }

   closedir(d);
}
```

Comment: Don't call `malloc()`, that is a leak -- the result is overwritten.

Comment: It will be followed by a free call. The intention was to demonstrate readdir() call.....

Comment: That won't fix anything, since at that point `e == NULL`.  **The call to `malloc()` is wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

In Unix,  [readdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) ; in Windows, see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)  for FindFirstFile(). Then go file by file in a loop and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This web page seems to have what you want.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Opening-a-Directory