# How can I rename files of which I don't know the extension?

Tags: c++, windows, rename

I have a directory with these files:

```
one.txt
two.mp3
three.bmp
```

Is there any way to rename files using [MoveFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239%28VS.85%29.aspx) but without specifying the extension of the file (all the files have different filenames)?

If not, how can I rename these files to anything I want, when I only know the

```
one
two
three
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the underlying OS API to scan through the directory for files and compare each filename with your desired prefix. [Here is another question that shows you how to list the contents of a directory in Windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Once you know prefix read the filelist of the directory and find a valid filename with that prefix, and use that filename with the function.