# relative path for searching directory with FindFirstFile

Tags: c++, path, relative-path

in the directory containing my exe I have a folder called "saves".
I want to display the files this directory contains.

I used the code found here:
[Listing directory contents using C and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)

Now the tricky part.
if I use `.\\saves\\` as my directory it tells me that the path could not be found.
However if I use `..\\release\\saves\\` it works fine. But that's stupid. I don't want to go to the parent folder and than go back. Especially regarding that I don't know what name the user gives to the directory containing the exe (in my case it's "release" but who knows what the user does :-D).

I read through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths but it didn't help very much.

I also tried `saves\\` or `.\saves\\` but it doesn't work either.

I hope somebody can tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually doing nothing wrong in code -- you've been launching the project from Visual Studio, which sets the Working Directory to the parent of the Release/Debug folders.

Go to Project->Settings(Properties)->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Working Directory

You can also run the exe outside of VS and the relative paths will behave like you expect.

Answer (score 2):

If it is relative from the path to the executable, and not from the path of the current working directory, you could use [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain the full path to the executable. Then, remove the name of the executable from the end of the path and build the paths using that:

```
std::string executable_directory_path()
{
    std::vector<char> full_path_exe(MAX_PATH);

    for (;;)
    {
        const DWORD result = GetModuleFileName(NULL,
                                               &full_path_exe[0],
                                               full_path_exe.size());

        if (result == 0)
        {
            // Report failure to caller.
        }
        else if (full_path_exe.size() == result)
        {
            // Buffer too small: increase size.
            full_path_exe.resize(full_path_exe.size() * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            // Success.
            break;
        }
    } 

    // Remove executable name.
    std::string result(full_path_exe.begin(), full_path_exe.end());
    std::string::size_type i = result.find_last_of("\\/");
    if (std::string::npos != i) result.erase(i);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake was using `\\saves\\`and forgeting to specify a search parameter/string
You should use:

```
saves\\*
```

this will search for any file or folder

Comment: Hey, i add a search mask via `sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `boost::filesystem` 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm.

As a bonus you will get operating system independent code.