# How to list a directory recursively

Tags: c, windows, recursion

I'm looking to list and store the contents of a directory in a struct using C on Windows.

I got a problem with stat(), I don't really understand this line

```
if (statut.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
```

So I want to understand how it works for checking if it's a directory or a file?

Comment: i  => I, code block on new line + 4 spaces

Comment: Learn binary numeric system and everything will be clear.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean , can develop your comment?

Comment: i know it is a masque but but i dont know what is doing exactly .

Comment: yes just the how the _stat works , i understand the bitwise.

Comment: This shows how to recursively enumerate files on Windows using C. It also shows how to determine if the "file" is a directory or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows/2315808#comment76685367_2315808

Answer (score 0):

`stat()` retrieves a block of information describing the specified file. Directories are *also* files. A directory can be thought of as a file that contains other files.

So, in the file's `st_mode`, you can see whether the current file is actually a directory by checking for the presence of the `S_IFDIR` bit.

Comment: but when it's not a directory, it writes _not a directory_ and i dont want that , because i want to manipulate the files inside the directory.

Comment: ?? "It" (stat / S_IFDIR) doesn't write anything. If *your program* doesn't do what you want it to do, change it.